# Sobrecarga de operador ==

Tags: c++, sobrecarga

```
bool Stock::operator== (const Stock& stk){

if ( this->get_resource() == (stk.get_resource()) )
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Eu criei esse método para sobrecarregar as operações de uma classe, porém, quando eu instancio ponteiros dessa classe e inicializo-os, seto valores e vejo se um objeto é igual ao outro o método que deveria retornar `TRUE`, visto que os valores são iguais, não retorna.

```
int main (){

    Stock* stk1 = new Stock();
    Stock* stk2 = new Stock();

    stk1->set_resource(10);
    stk2->set_resource(10);

    cout << stk1->get_resource() << endl;
    cout << stk2->get_resource() << endl;

    if(stk1 == stk2)
        cout << "IGUAL" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

O `if` nunca é executado.

Comment: Experimenta tirar o `this`. O erro pode estar em outro lugar do código.

Answer (score 2):

O erro está em uma parte do código que não foi mostrada pelo OP.

Estou colocando o código modificado porque o código original é um péssimo exemplo de C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stock
{
   private:
      int resource;

   public:
      int get_resource() { return resource; }
      void set_resource(int r) { resource = r; }
      bool operator==(const Stock& stk) { return resource == stk.resource; }
};

int main ()
{
    Stock stk1, stk2;

    stk1.set_resource(10);
    stk2.set_resource(10);

    cout << stk1.get_resource() << endl;
    cout << stk2.get_resource() << endl;

    if (stk1 == stk2)
       cout << "IGUAL" << endl;
    else
       cout << "DIFERENTE" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```